# Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

My code is to get the base64 string of the image loaded in the `<img>` tag. It only works when the source of my image is stored locally. But not on online url. I get my images from firebase

html:

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let img of Images" >
 <img id="preview" class="images"  [src]="img" >
</ion-slide>
```

typescript:

```
imageTObase64 () {
 const c = document.createElement('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
 const ctx = c.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
 const img = document.getElementById('preview') as HTMLImageElement;
 img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
 ctx.drawImage(img, img.naturalHeight, img.naturalWidth);
 const base64String = c.toDataURL();
 console.log(base64String);
}
```

The error I get:

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used the method above because it only works for local images. I downloaded the images from firebase directly